# How to group data with similar dates in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have two csv files. Both the files contain Date, Stock, Open, High,Low,Close column of a single day. I made one dataframe from these two files. So, in this single dataframe 1st the data of Stock 1 is printed from day open to day close and then data of Stock 2 from day open to day end .The data is of 15 min interval and a day starts with 2019-01-01 09:15:00 and ends with 2019-01-01 15:15:00.

What I want is to create a dataframe where data of stock1 at 2019-01-01 09:15:00 is printed and then the data of stock2 at the same time and so on for 2019-01-01 09:30:00, 2019-01-01 09:45:00....

Check the image:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

---

#### New Answer:

After reading your response I figured the best course of action for your issue would be moving your data to a 2-index DataFrame format using [Pandas MultiIndex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html)

```py
arrays = [
    np.array(["bar", "bar", "baz", "baz", "foo", "foo", "qux", "qux"]),
    np.array(["one", "two", "one", "two", "one", "two", "one", "two"]),
]

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 4), index=arrays)

df
Out[16]: 
                0         1         2         3
bar one -0.424972  0.567020  0.276232 -1.087401
    two -0.673690  0.113648 -1.478427  0.524988
baz one  0.404705  0.577046 -1.715002 -1.039268
    two -0.370647 -1.157892 -1.344312  0.844885
foo one  1.075770 -0.109050  1.643563 -1.469388
    two  0.357021 -0.674600 -1.776904 -0.968914
qux one -1.294524  0.413738  0.276662 -0.472035
    two -0.013960 -0.362543 -0.006154 -0.923061
```

---

#### Old Answer

---

You can use the pandas `concat` method. If their index format matches, the Pandas API will take care of the rest.

```py
import pandas as pd
import datetime

idx = pd.date_range("2018-01-01", periods=5, freq="H")
ts = pd.DataFrame(range(len(idx)), index=idx)

|                     |   0 |
|:--------------------|----:|
| 2018-01-01 00:00:00 |   0 |
| 2018-01-01 01:00:00 |   1 |
| 2018-01-01 02:00:00 |   2 |
| 2018-01-01 03:00:00 |   3 |
| 2018-01-01 04:00:00 |   4 |

idy = pd.date_range("2018-01-02", periods=10, freq="H")
tsy = pd.DataFrame(range(len(idy)), index=idy)

|                     |   0 |
|:--------------------|----:|
| 2018-01-02 00:00:00 |   0 |
| 2018-01-02 01:00:00 |   1 |
| 2018-01-02 02:00:00 |   2 |
| 2018-01-02 03:00:00 |   3 |
| 2018-01-02 04:00:00 |   4 |
| 2018-01-02 05:00:00 |   5 |
| 2018-01-02 06:00:00 |   6 |
| 2018-01-02 07:00:00 |   7 |
| 2018-01-02 08:00:00 |   8 |
| 2018-01-02 09:00:00 |   9 |
```

Result:

```py
pd.concat([ts, tsy])

|                     |   0 |
|:--------------------|----:|
| 2018-01-01 00:00:00 |   0 |
| 2018-01-01 01:00:00 |   1 |
| 2018-01-01 02:00:00 |   2 |
| 2018-01-01 03:00:00 |   3 |
| 2018-01-01 04:00:00 |   4 |
| 2018-01-02 00:00:00 |   0 |
| 2018-01-02 01:00:00 |   1 |
| 2018-01-02 02:00:00 |   2 |
| 2018-01-02 03:00:00 |   3 |
| 2018-01-02 04:00:00 |   4 |
| 2018-01-02 05:00:00 |   5 |
| 2018-01-02 06:00:00 |   6 |
| 2018-01-02 07:00:00 |   7 |
| 2018-01-02 08:00:00 |   8 |
| 2018-01-02 09:00:00 |   9 |
```

Comment: I have already used concat to create a single dataframe. What i want is to order them according to date. For example, first data of Tatasteel at 9:15 and then data of Tatamotors at 9:15 and so on.

Comment: oh, then I'd advise you on moving your data to a 2-index DataFrame using pandas [MultiIndex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html)